# What are new tasks in data mining?

Tags: data-mining

Beside five "classical" data mining tasks

- regression and classification
- association rules
- clustering
- outlier detection
- dimension reduction and visuzalization,

I recently found sources regarding some new ones including

- [contrast and change mining](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/widm.27/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false)
- [graph mining](http://www.liacs.nl/~erwin/dbdm2009/GraphMining.pdf)
- [opinion mining](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/opinion-mining-sentiment-analysis-survey.html)

Are there any other new tasks that I should know?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From a very broad sense of Data Mining and mixing slightly tasks and methods, these are my two cents...

Sentiment Analysis (although you have said opinion mining)
Relational Classification
Relationship Extraction (Knowledge Discovery)
Recommendation
Time-Aware Information Retrieval
Time-Aware Prediction (Series Prediction)
Summarisation
Personalisation

In general, a good idea is to find a conference related to the topic you want to observe (KDD for Data Mining for instance) and see the sessions per topic they have in order to discover new tasks/applications.

Regards,